# How to count consecutive 0's in between values of 1 in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

there's a question that asks for a given vector that contains 1's and 0's, return a vector that gives the number of 0's in between each one.
For example:
input = [0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0]
output = [1 3 1 0 0 3 1 0 2]

my code:

```
function y = count_zero(x)
y = []
count = 0
for i = 1:length(x)
if x(i) == 0
count = count +1
elseif x(i) == 1
count = 0
end
y = horzcat(y,count)
end 
end
```

I know that my code is wrong, but I couldn't find a way to modify this code to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only append to `y` when you hit the next `1`, not for each element in `x`. You can achieve that by moving the concatenation within the `elseif`, but then you also need to do it right at the end to handle the final element

You should use indentation to make your code more readable and semi-colons at the end of each line to suppress command line output.

```
function y = count_zero(x)
y = [];
count = 0;
for i = 1:length(x)
    if x(i) == 0
        count = count +1;
    elseif x(i) == 1
        y = horzcat(y,count);
        count = 0;
    end
end
y = horzcat(y,count);
```

If you wanted a short way to do this, you could `find` the indices where `x==1` (appending a 1 to the start and end of `x` to handle the edge cases) and then take the difference between those indices. The number of zeros is one less than the `diff` of the indices.

```
y = diff(find([1,x,1]==1))-1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I got 2 failed tests. when x = 1, y = 0. but I got y = [0 0]. and if x = [0 0 1 0 0 1], y should equal [2 2], and I got y = [2 2 0], I can't understand why

Comment: for the case x=1, if proceed from inside to outside syntax wise: `find` give as result 1 2 3 since the array  passed to it  is [ 1 1 1], so a 1x3. The `diff` will output [1 1] since it is the difference between the elements, reducing the size to 1x2. Then there is the `-1` which will get us the final output of [0 0], size 1x2

Comment: for the case x= [0 0 1 0 0 1], same method: `find` will give use [1 4 7 8] , so 1x4. `diff` will do its thing, reducing to 1x3 with [3 3 1] as output. `-1` doesnt change output size, [2 2 0] 1x3.

Comment: You didn't include those test cases in the question, and I'm not sure the original problem description describes why this is expected behaviour. So when a string ends with a `0` you want to count those zeros (note this isn't zeros "between each one" as in the question, because there isn't a final one), but when it ends with a `1` you don't want to count the end as a `0`? You can just add this test case, `if x(end)==1; y(end)=[]; end`.

Comment: basically the extra numbers size you see are derived from the ones padding `[1 x 1]` which is necessary for the use of  ´diff´ which requires (only in this case to provide the correct values) the array to start and end with 1